# java can system out result in out of memory issues

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, applet, out-of-memory

This is a theoretical question .

Can a flood of  system out on java applet , cause applet to go out of memory ?

If yes what would be an easy solution to remove multiple sysout  spanning across multiple files ?

Comment: Extremely unlikely. Provide more information about your issue.

Comment: chrylis thanks ..  I would debug more but just wanted to clarify this if there is some memory management logic which could be involved here due to multiple system outs that I used . So its not related .. thats important info for me :)

Comment: If it concerns you just `System.out.close();` on app startup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single System.out.println(x) can cause an out of memory error, if x.toString() uses too much memory.

> Can a flood of system out on java applet , cause applet to go out of memory ?

It is size of the resulting String which matters, not the number.  More messages will be slower, but make no difference to the amount of free memory after a Full GC and that is what counts.